# iPhone 4s 6.1.2 version UIViewcontroller gets refreshed on taking a image using camera

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, audio, camera

I've recorded an audio and then captured an image using my application's camera.

After that when I return to my view controller the recording data is reset or its refreshed. No recorded file exists.

Why does this issue happen only on iPhone 4s? Why does the view gets reset after using camera?

Comment: Are you saving it before returning to your view controller?

Comment: @vin yes i am saving the image in a class scope variable then resumes the other functionalities

Comment: have you tried putting an NSLog to see where exactly it is saving? are you using the same URL once you return to your view controller?

Comment: Please put some code in the question so that it can be more clear to understand.

Comment: Yes the same URL is retained to retrieve the image for other purposes and her is no issue with the image,the issue is the controller gets refreshed by deleting mi already recorded audio file only in 4s

Answer (score 0):

Because when you dismiss the ImagePickerController then your `ViewWillAppear` method will be called & All functionaly has been reset same as When view loads first time.

**You need to save the functionality or check the condition on viewWillAppear method.**

**YOu can also set the fiunctionality on `Cancelbutton press` Or `ImagePicker is dismiiss` delegate method of ImagePicker to save the functionlity.**

Comment: yes i have handled this condition and it works perfectly in other os versions too.......but it fails in the iPhone 4s.Is her any os dependency or any calling delegates differs in 4S ??

Comment: No, According to me, It is not any difference in that. Can you post your code??